# httpd.conf redirect / to 8080 and redirect /index.html to /app/index.html

Tags: httpd, apache2, httpd.conf

How can create this conf on httpd.conf:

user access http://site and see content from http://site:8080

but

when they access http://site/index.html, it should redirect to http://site/app/index.html

which is the content from http://site:8080/app/index.html

and when user access http://site:8080/index.html it should keep the acess like that. Do not redirect to http://site:8080/app/index.html

I tried this conf on httpd.conf:

```
Redirect "/index.html" "/app/index.html"

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
RewriteEngine On
```

But the index.html to app/index.html is not working.

Can it be done with httpd.conf?

the 8080 is on tomcat and the 80 is on httpd.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.html$ /app/index.html [L,R]
```